# Calc1: Min, Inf, Max and Sup of sets

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Simplify the following sets and, if existing, determine Minimum, Maximum, Infimum and Supremum in ℝ and prove your claim.

b) $\bigcup\limits_{z \in \mathbb{Z} } {]z,z + 1[} $

c) $\bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}  } {[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$      Hint: Use the Archimedean axiom.

---

So my guess would be (**edited**)

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
   & Min & Inf & Max & Sup \\ \hline
b) & -   & -∞  & -   & +∞  \\ \hline
c) & 0   & 0   & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

But how do you prove it properly? And are my assumptions correct?

Comment: $1/\infty$ in this context means $0$. Its also a theorem that if the max is defined, then it equals the sup (and likewise for min and inf).

Comment: Yeah, Im familiar with that theorem. I think its clear that it also applies to my assumptions. Doesn't it? With 1/∞ I wanted to express the the lowest upper barrier will be close to zero but it will never become zero. So how would i get started on a prove? Any ideas?

Comment: The max and the min are zero, and saying that they’re not is factually (and probably) incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Set B is $\mathbb R-\mathbb Z$, and set C is $\{0\}$. Given that, do you see how to prove it? Both proofs are one sentence.

Comment: No, I don't follow. Sorry.

I can see how B is ℝ−ℤ but I have not made the jump on how the prove works /o\

Why is set C {0}? I see that the interval becomes smaller and smaller with each intersections but I wouldn't necessarily deduce that it is {0}. I thought of it like an asymptote, which it will never reach.

Comment: @kiaora I would strongly recommend you reread your notes or whatever resource you’re learning from. The proofs are incredibly simple and if you don’t know them, you probably don’t understand the related concepts very well.

Comment: @kiaora There is no such thing as an infinite intersection with that behavior. An infinite intersection is the set of all points in every part of the intersection. The only such number is $0$. This is a common confusion, but again I would recommend you reread your notes and try to learn the basic definitions of these concepts.

Comment: @kiaora For example, the proof is almost identical to the proof that $\mathbb R$ has infinite sup. Do you know how to prove that? There’s even a way to word the proof such that a single proof works word-for-word for both sets.

Comment: Since ℝ is not bound it will go up to ∞, therefore its sup (and max) must also be ∞?

Comment: @kiaora It’s sup is infinity, yes. It’s max is undefined. You can say the exact same thing about $\mathbb R-\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Wouldn't the max = sup if you interpret ℝ as a set? Then the largest lower barrier within the set would be ∞, wouldn't it?

Comment: @kiaora $\infty$ is not a real number.

Comment: Oh, I see now (I think). Thank you. “The resulting union of intervals can also be written like  ℝ−ℤ and since neither ℝ nor ℤ are bound the resulting Inf would be  -∞ and the Sup would be +∞” Would this be correct?

Also regarding c) I still have trouble grasping it. How would Archimedean axiom be of any help?

Comment: @kiaora No, that’s not correct. Firstly, it’s not that resulting union “can be written like R-Z.” It is R-Z. They are precisely the same set. Secondly, the fact that Z is unbounded has the potential to cause issues. $\mathbb R-[0,\infty)$ has bounded sup! Ty need to show that R-Z is an unbounded set, preferably by giving a sequence that is unbounded within the set.

Comment: The achremedian axiom tells you that for every $k$ in $(0,1]$ there exists a natural number $n$ such that $1/n < k$. It follows from this that if $k\in (0,1]$ then $k$ is not in the intersection, since it’s excluded from the interva $[0,1/n]$